# How to find the answer of this puzzle: $17 \times 4 = 68 + 25 = 93$?

Tags: puzzle

[image]

Answer: 17 x 4 = 68 + 25 = 93

I have asked the guy who got the answer right [in this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ThatsInsane/comments/g5wn0d/lock_down_puzzle_solve_it_without_repitition_of/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf&utm_term=link), but hadn’t get reply from him. Do we use trial and error?

Comment: I *think* this question was asked here recently. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @Blue I solved this with Prolog the other day: $17×4=68+25=93$

Comment: I’m sorry but why this posted as my reputation was less then 10?

Comment: Casablanca, @Blue edited in the image for you.

Comment: @amWhy I see, hardly sees it

Comment: Found the previous version: ["Is it possible for this puzzle to be solved without the use of computational software?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1666642/409). From 2016, but it got bumped by a recent (unhelpful) answer. Voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: There is also a much more recent version of this question on [Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97381/numbers-1-9-all-used-up). I would suggest asking similar questions on Puzzling SE as they are a better fit there.

Comment: @amWhy no, not even the comments